# Bloc is either calling multiple times or not getting called at all

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc

I have 2 screens

> 1. Screen A
> 2. Screen B

I go from `screen A` to `Screen B` via the below code

```
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screen_b');
    },
```

Screen B code

```
class ScreenB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenBState createState() => _ScreenBState();
}

class _ScreenBState extends State<ScreenB> {

   SampleBloc sampleBloc;

    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState();
       sampleBloc = BlocProvider.of<SampleBloc>(context);

       sampleBloc.stream.listen((state) {
          // this is getting called multiple times.
       }
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
       super.dispose();
       sampleBloc.clear(); // If i add this, no event is firing from second time i come to the page. initState() is being called i checked so sampleBloc is not null.
    }
   
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ....
           onTap: () {
              sampleBloc.add(CreateSampleEvent());
           },
       ....
    }

}
```

When i click tap to add `CreateSampleEvent` to the `sampleBloc` in Screen B, the 'sampleBloc.stream.listen' getting fired multiples times.

> Sample outcome
>
> Step 1. First do `sampleBloc.add (tap)` -> sampleBloc.stream.listen
> fired one    time
> Step 2. **Go back to Screen A and come back to
> Screen B**     Second go `sampleBloc.add (tap)` -> In one case i saw
> the firing    takes place in a pair of 2 times, and in other times the
> firing takes    place in pair of 4 times.

```
class SampleBloc extends Bloc<SampleEvent, SampleState> {
  final SampleRepository sampleRepository;

  SampleBloc({this.sampleRespository}) : super(null);


  @override
  Stream<SampleState> mapEventToState(SampleEvent event) async* {
    if (event is SampleEvent) {
      yield* mapSampleEventToState();
    }
  }

  Stream<SampleEvent> mapSampleEventToState() async* {
    yield SampleInProgressState();
    try {
      String sampleId = await sampleRepository.createSample();
      if (sampleId != null) {
        yield SampleCompletedState(sampleId, uid);
      } else {
        yield SampleFailedState();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      yield SampleFailedState();
    }
  }
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Are you only listening in the `initState()`? Aso, if you could post your `SampleBloc` it could help.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo Yes sir.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Did you cancel the stream subscription when going back to Screen A? Did you implement the dispose in Screen B, could you add that code as well?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo added SampleBloc

Comment: @MidhunMP do you mean calling sampleBloc.clear() in dispose method of Screen B ?

Comment: Subscripion.cancel as mentioned in the below answer @SaurabhKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating a manual subscription (by fetching the Bloc and then listening to a `stream`) you'll also need to manually *cancel* that subscription when you're done with it, otherwise, the `SampleBloc` will just keep getting new subscriptions and yielding events to all of them.

For that, you can either:

1. Save the subscription and then cancel it in the `dispose()` method.

```
   SampleBloc sampleBloc;
   StreamSubscription _subscription;

    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState();
       sampleBloc = BlocProvider.of<SampleBloc>(context);

       _subscription = sampleBloc.stream.listen((state) {
          // this is getting called multiple times.
       }
    }
    
   @override
   void dispose() {
     _subscription.cancel();
     super.dispose();
   }
```

2. You can take advantage of the [`BlocListener`](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=bloclistener) from the package which is a widget that is disposed automatically, hence, removes the subscriptions it created.

```
BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    // do stuff here based on BlocA's state
  },
  child: Container(),
)
```

Comment: I like the second alternative. Was not aware of that feature. Will try out and let you know the outcome. Thanks a lot.